# Displaying images as a grid or a list

Tags: java, image, user-interface

Hii

I am working on an application where i need to display images from a folder selected by an user.All the images present in the folder should be displayed.I would like to know how to display them like a scrollable one in picasa , where we get the images at the bottom  or like a grid.

Please provide any sample codes to implement this .Any links demonstrating the same are highly appreciated.

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

See [How to Use a JList](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html). You can display them horizontally, vertically or in a grid.